# Chat window changes automatically when new message is received

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a chat application like whatsapp web and its almost completed
but i am having some trouble.

the problem is currently i have 2 user one is love123 and other is raja1234,
now when i click on raja1234 then raja1234 chat is loaded and displayed on right side, now raja1234 chat window is open and in this time i receive a message from love123 so what happen raja1234 chat window is replaced by love123 you can see in the image below, and i am giving dynamic value to the div.

[image]

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("messages").child(id);
                        var roomQuery = rootRef.limitToLast(20);
                        roomQuery.on('child_added', function(snapshot)
                        {
                               var name = snapshot.key;
                               var childData = snapshot.val();
                               var senderclass = '';
                               var senderImg = '';
                                if(childData.name == 'KuberSupport') {
                                        senderclass='sender';
                                        senderImg='sender-img';
                                }
                                else{
                                        senderclass='receiver';
                                        senderImg='receiver-img';
                                }

                               if(childData.file != '')
                                {
                                  var filePath = "'"+childData.file+"'";
                                    html += '<div class="row message-body"><div class="col-sm-12 message-main-receiver"> <div class="'+senderImg+'"><div class="message-text img-div" ><div id="lightgallery123" class="lightgallery lightgallery123"> <div data-src="'+ childData.file +'" > <img src="'+ childData.file +'"></div></div><div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-top:3px;"><p style="margin-left:-15px;color:#565555;font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;"> '+ childData.message +'</p></div><span class="message-time-img pull-right" style="margin-top: -15px;"> '+ childData.time +' </span></div></div></div></div>'; 
                                }
                                else{
                                    html += '<div class="row message-body"><div class="col-sm-12 message-main-receiver"><div class="'+senderclass+'"> <div class="message-text mrr-10" style="color:#565555;font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;">'+ childData.message +'<span class="message-time-img  msg-txt-ad" style="margin-top: -15px;"> '+ childData.time +' </span></div></div></div></div>';
                                }
                                var sid = $(this).attr('id');
                                $('.'+sid).html(html);
                                scrollToBottom();
                                $('.lightgallery123').lightGallery();
                                scrollToBottom();
                                roomQuery.off()
                             });
                             $('.'+id).html(html);
                             $('.lightgallery123').lightGallery();
```

//the genereated div has dynamic class name raja1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach a listener with `on(...)` it keeps listening for changes from the database until you either call `off()` or until the page unloads/reloads. It seems like neither of those happens when you switch to the other chat room, so your callback keeps getting called with for new messages in the old chat room.

To stop listening, keep track of your current room query with:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("messages").child(id);
var roomQuery = rootRef.limitToLast(20);
roomQuery.on('child_added', function(snapshot) 
  ...
                     {
```

And then before updating the `rootRef`, remove the listener on the existing `roomQuery` with:

```
roomQuery.off();
```

Comment: i tried your code but it solved my problem but its not showing real time chat

Comment: Right now where you have the call to `off()` is right after you get the first data. If that what you'd want, you might as well use `once()` which implicitly does the same. You should call `off()` when the user switches to a new chat room, so that you stop receiving messages from the previous room they were listening to.